# how to make InputStream for local xml file

Tags: android, inputstream, xmlpullparser

I'm beginner android app developer.

I'm going to parse xml file saved in local storage.

But I don't have idea how to make InputStream.

Please tell me some advice. pre-Thanks!!

```
... APP_LOCAL_DIR = "/data/com.qqq.qqq/appname/"; 
String xml_file_path = APP_LOCAL_DIR.getAbsoluteFile() +"/" + YYYYMM + ".xml";

try {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setValidating(false);
        XmlPullParser myxml = factory.newPullParser(); 

        InputStream raw = ________________________???? 
        myxml.setInput(raw, null);

 .......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is coming from a file, so you want to use a `FileInputStream` which extends `InputStream`:

```
InputStream raw = new FileInputStream(new File(xml_file_path));
```

Comment: any example ? on xml_file_path.